# sed replace delimiter following integer

Tags: text-processing, sed

Given a filename `chrIII:834297-835206:-.miRanda.txt` I would like to produce a minimal bed format (tab separated data):

```
chrIII  834297  835206  -
```

I'm having difficulty telling `sed` to convert only the first `-` delimiter that succeeds an integer (i.e don't mess with the strand information, the second occurrence). My attempt `echo *.miRanda.txt | sed 's/.miRanda.txt//g' | sed 's/:/\t/g; s/[0-9]-/\t/g'` is incorrect, I would be grateful if someone could help (I suspect I must surround `[0-9]` with some pattern but I am struggling to google this without knowing the terminology).

Solution does not necessarily demand `sed`.

Comment: With "terminology", do you mean regular expressions (or regex for short)?

Comment: I guess what I mean is not being able to explicitly verbalise `([0-9]+)` or `(chr[^:]+)` in programming parlance. I think it would help when searching for answers.

Comment: The `g` (global) modifier on `s/[0-9]-/\t/g` is telling sed to repeat the substitution multiple times for each line, repeat until it can't find any more matches to replace.  If you don't want it to repeat, don't use `g`.   i.e. `s/[0-9]-/\t/` tells sed to replace the first match only.  `s/[0-9]-/\t/g` tells sed to replace every match it finds.  This is hinted at in @terdon's answer, but not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way (using GNU `sed` or any other that supports `-E`):

```
$ echo chrIII:834297-835206:-.miRanda.txt |     
    sed -E 's/^(chr[^:]+):([0-9]+)-([0-9]+):([^.]+).*/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4/'
chrIII  834297  835206  -
```

Note that this assumes you can never have a `.` as the 4th field (the name in the bed file). If that's not a safe assumption and you need to use the extension, you can do:

```
$ echo chrIII:834297-835206:-.miRanda.txt | 
    sed -E 's/^(chr[^:]+):([0-9]+)-([0-9]+):(.+)\.miRanda.txt/\1\t\2\t\3\t\4/'
chrIII  834297  835206  -
```

Also note that a minimal bed format doesn't need a 4th field at all. This is a valid bed file:

```
chrIII  834297  835206
```

Finally, your approach is *almost* there, albeit slightly more complicated than is strictly needed. You were removing the last integer from the start position because of `s/[0-9]-/\1\t/` which replaces both the number and the `-` with a tab. This is basically the same command as yours, only tweaked slightly to fix this issue and to remove unnecessary `g`lobal operators:

```
$ echo chrIII:834297-835206:-.miRanda.txt | 
    sed 's/\.miRanda.txt//' | 
        sed -E 's/:/\t/g; s/([0-9])-/\1\t/'
chrIII  834297  835206  -
```

I don't know why you said that failed for you.

Comment: Thanks, @terdon. FYI my initial attempt is no good because it removes the last int from the genomic start position.

Comment: @BarryD you're welcome. And yes, you're quite right, I completely missed that it removed the last number from the start position, sorry! I added a corrected version of yours for completeness. By the way, you might be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].